# NSScrollView containing NSStackView. Why the NSStackView items from bottom to Top?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsscrollview, nsstackview

The NSScrollView containing a NSStackView. The NSStackView's items will add in runtime.The new NSStackView's items are from bottom to top, but I want they are from top to bottom.
[image]
[image]

The main.storyboard

[image]

The ViewController

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var todoList:[Todo] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var todosStackView: NSStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var todosScrollView: NSScrollView!

    @IBAction func onEnter(sender: NSTextField) {
        let todo = Todo()
        todo.content = sender.stringValue
        self.todoList.append(todo)

        let todoItemView = TodoItem()
        todoItemView.setButtonType(.SwitchButton)
        todoItemView.todo=todo
        todosStackView.addView(todoItemView, inGravity: .Top)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

The checkbox button class

```
import Cocoa

class TodoItem: NSButton {
    var todo:Todo!{
        didSet {
            self.title = self.todo.content
            self.state = self.todo.done ? NSOnState : NSOffState
        }
    }

    func completeTodo(){
        if(self.state == NSOnState){
            self.todo.done = true
        }else{
            self.todo.done = false
        }
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        self.setButtonType(.SwitchButton)
        self.target = self
        self.action = #selector(self.completeTodo)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, NSClipViews (and the base NSView) are not flipped and so coordinates (and scroll view positioning) are relative to the bottom left.

You can subclass NSClipView and override `isFlipped` to return `true`.  Then in IB, set the clip view of the scroll view to that custom class.

Comment: You are my Saviour! Thank You very much!

Comment: create `class NSFlippedStackView: NSStackView` and overides isFlipped=true also works for me

Answer (score 0):

You have your view (the parent of stack view) anchored to parent clip view via leading and bottom anchor. Try using leading and top instead. Note: your stack view itself seems to be aligned properly.